# How to make RabbitMQ redeliver a message when it doesn't receive a ACK after a certain time?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

If I understand AMQP correctly:

> After a message (delivery) is pushed to a consumer, the server waits for
>   its ACK, if ACK is not received when the message reaches its TTL,
>   the message is discarded.

What I want is for the message to be requeued when ACK is not received after a certain time, how can I do this?

And I also need to requeue the message at most 3 times. I know I can do this on the client side by keeping a counter and reject the message (NACK) when the counter reaches 3. But can this be done on the server side?

Comment: This Q/A is related to second part of question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158310/how-do-i-set-a-number-of-retry-attempts-in-rabbitmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you ask can't be done on RabbitMQ server side, unless you write plugin to do that, so probably you will have to do what you want on a client side.

Comment: Additionally, you can take a look on [Plugins](https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html) page (incl. [Community Plugins](https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html)), maybe you will find something useful there to adapt to your needs.

Comment: I have the same requirement. Redeliver a message after a certain time if acknowledge is not given. I was looking if i can configure rabbitmq to deliver unacknowledged messages after a regular interval.