# RabbitMQ error when setting up Learning Transport with NServiceBus

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I have been using the learning transport with NServiceBus successfully whilst building a prototype.

I have then added RabbitMQ support to it which works fine.

When I switch (via app.config) back to learning transport, I get the following error even though RabbitMQ is not being configured

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key (RabbitMQ.Routing TopologySupportsDelayedDelivery) was not present in the dictionary

My learning transport code is as follows :-

```
    public EndpointConfiguration ConfigureEndPoint(ILog logger, ServiceBusConfiguration config)
    {
        try
        {
            // set up server endpoint
            logger.Debug($"Creating server endpoint {config.ServerEndPointName}.");
            var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(config.ServerEndPointName);
            logger.Debug($"Server endpoint {config.ServerEndPointName} created.");
            logger.Debug($"Setting up persistence.");
            endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<LearningPersistence>();
            logger.Debug($"Persistence set up.");
            logger.Debug($"Setting up transport.");
            endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<LearningTransport>();
            logger.Debug($"Transport set up.");

            endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
            return endpointConfiguration;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error($"Could not configure service endpoint.", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

My RabbitMQ code is

```
    public EndpointConfiguration ConfigureEndPoint(ILog logger, ServiceBusConfiguration config)
    {
        try
        {
            // set up server endpoint
            logger.Debug($"Creating server endpoint {config.ServerEndPointName}.");
            var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(config.ServerEndPointName);
            logger.Debug($"Server endpoint {config.ServerEndPointName} created.");
            logger.Debug($"Setting up transport.");
            var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();
            //transport.UseConventionalRoutingTopology();
            transport.ConnectionString(config.RabbitMQConnectionString);
            logger.Debug($"Transport set up.");

            endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();

            logger.Debug($"Setting up persistence.");
            endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
            logger.Debug($"Persistence set up.");
            return endpointConfiguration;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error($"Could not configure service endpoint.", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I am using NServiceBus v6.4.3 and NServiceBus.RabbitMQ v4.4.1

Any ideas?

I can't figure out why RabbitMQ is complaining when I am not even invoking it when configured for learning transport.

Comment: Yuck, why use RMQ with NSB?  The former _[doesn't even have message retry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23161921/585968)_

Comment: I don't have a choice in the technology used.

Comment: Most likely, the assembly that's not referenced has remained in the bin folder, which will get scanned and picked up by NSB. The 'fix' would be to do a Clean and then build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: exclude RabbitMQ transport dll from scanning.

https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/assembly-scanning

Example:

```
scanner.ExcludeAssemblies("NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ");
```

Long answer: such behavior is very confusing and personally should be fixed by NServiceBus team

Comment: Most likely, the assembly that's not referenced has remained in the bin folder, which will get scanned and picked up by NSB. The 'fix' would be to do a Clean and then build.

Comment: The trouble is that the transport can be switched via configuration so I can't remove the dll from the build. Both need to be carried.

Comment: That gets around the problem.

Comment: _"The trouble is that the transport can be switched via configuration so I can't remove the dll from the build"_. Mind to expand on that? Why do you need both transport to be found in the same endpoint and switch between the two using configuration? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you observe is caused by the assembly scanning of a project that references RabbitMQ but does not use it.

In any case, where a project references RabbitMQ transport without selecting it as a transport, the exclusion from scanning is the currently proposed solution.

We track it under https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/issues/471