# Rabbit MQ .Net Delivery Count

Tags: rabbitmq

jms queues has jmsdeliverycount.If message read from queue one more time we can track with this property.What is the equvaliant of this RabbitMQ .net.
I want to check how many times this message read from queue(in transactional reads)

Comment: Solution is possible now. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158310/how-do-i-set-a-number-of-retry-attempts-in-rabbitmq

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is nothing out-of-the-box. All you get is a redelivery flag to say it has been redelivered, but not how many times.

You can track this [issue](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/502).

Answer (score 1):

Quorum queues track the number of redeliveries, in the `x-delivery-count` header. [See here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#poison-message-handling)

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2013) to add the same to classic queues.