# RabbitMQ - Retry max times before finally placing in Dead Letter Queue

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to use Dead Letter Exchanges to handle both retrying a task and archiving tasks that failed more than `retry_max` number of times?

Most articles I've read set it up so that when a task fails, it is `nack`ed so the task is sent to a `retry-queue` via a DLX. `retry-queue` has a TTL and is configured to send the dead message back to `worker-queue`.

What I would like to do is to send the message to a different queue, e.g.: `dead-queue`, when the maximum number of retries fails for manual intervention later. Is this possible using `nack`?

The diagram in the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158310/how-do-i-set-a-number-of-retry-attempts-in-rabbitmq) suggests that I can somehow `nack` the message when the max retries is exceeded and send it to a "Fail Exchange" but I'm not sure how I can `nack` the message and have it delivered to a different exchange.

Comment: There is no way to automatically do this, so you need to handle it in your code, preferably using the x-death header.

Comment: What I asked wasn't possible. I've decided to continue using `nack` to have RabbitMQ send the task from `worker-queue` to the `retry-queue` and when `retry_max` is exceeded, I use `ack` to remove the message from `worker-queue` and explicitly code the consumer to handle sending the old task as a new task to `dead-queue`. Not ideal because the consumer/worker can fail between the `ack` and sending the task as a new job to `dead-queue` but compromises must be made.