# is it possible to retries unack message in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Now I am using rabbitMQ to consume message using Java code client, this is my client code:

```
@RabbitHandler
    public void handle(@Payload byte[] message, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws IOException {
        String messageContext = new String(message, "UTF-8");
        ReportWalletConsumeRecord record = JSON.parseObject(messageContext, ReportWalletConsumeRecord.class);
        asyncService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                MyContext.setTenant(record.getTenantId());
                asyncFlushRecord(record, channel, tag);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("save message failed：" + JSON.toJSONString(record), e);
            }
        });
    }
```

but sometimes the flush failed and the message turned to unack, is it possible to repull the unack message and try again(1-3 times)?

Comment: there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654475/consuming-not-acknowledge-messages-from-rabbitmq), see if it helps you